# watch expression is not picking up on model change from ng-change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, angularjs, haml

I have the following
Rails HAML:

```
 = select_tag "some-class",
                        options_for_select([['None', '']], ''),
                        { class: 'some-other-class',
                          'ng-model' => 'someModel',
                          'ng-options' => 'option.name for option in someList',
                          'ng-change' => 'updateSelected()'}
```

Angular Controller:

```
  scope.updateSelected = ->
       #logic for updating model lives here. Model updates successfully by using some values defined within scope. Includes the following:
       scope.someModel = "some_new_value"
```

Angular Directive:

```
  SomeClassDirective= ->
       restrict: 'C'

       link: (scope, element, attrs) ->

            monitorFormFields = (newValue, oldValue) ->
                   console.log "this is the inner function call"
                   #logic for setting the inner _destroy field lives here

            scope.$watch 'someModel', monitorFormFields
```

However, when the Select List value is changed, 'this is the inner function call' never prints.(it does print when the directive first initializes, ie at page load). My question therefore is: Why isn't the $watch expression triggering, and how do I get it to trigger?

Thanks!

Comment: `ng-click` supports `$event`, but `ng-change` does not seem to.

Comment: any suggestions on how to hack around this limitation?

Comment: There is probably a way to do what you want in Angular without the event.  What do you want to do with the event?

Comment: I would like to from the element fetch a sibling with [_destroy] in the name and set it to either "0" or "1" depending on the value of the select box

Comment: You can `$scope.$watch( someModel, function() {})` to fire an handler when the selection changes.

Comment: Also, I would rethink the process. It's against angular best practices to do dom manipulation in the controller. It means you have not maintained clean separation of concerns (i.e. mvc). If you provide more context, we can suggest a more "angular" approach.

Comment: I've edited the question to take the comments into account. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this HTML:

```
<select class="some-class" ng-model="someModel" 
   ng-options="option.name for option in someList"></select>
```

Here is a directive that will watch for a change to `someModel`:

```
myApp.directive('someClass', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var monitorFormFields = function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("this is in the inner function call");
      }
      scope.$watch('someModel', monitorFormFields);
    }
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.someList = [{ name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name2' }];
```

Note that you don't need to call a controller method to update `someModel` -- Angular does that automatically for us because of the `ng-model` attribute.  So, the directive only needs to $watch for a change to that $scope property.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/6Apuj/).

---

> I would like to from the element fetch a sibling with [_destroy] in the name and set it to either "0" or "1" depending on the value of the select box.

A more Angular approach would be to have model properties control whether "0" or "1" is displayed.  E.g., in your controller:

```
$scope.destroy1 = "0";
$scope.destroy2 = "0";
```

In your HTML:

```
<div>{{destroy1}}</div>
<div>{{destroy2}}</div>
```

In monitorFormFields() you can change the values of these scope properties, and the view will automatically update -- there is no need to "find" siblings or update .val()ues.

Comment: Thank you! the pertinent information was that ng-change is not necessary! (In fact ng-change was breaking my logic, not sure why, not entirely sure I care). As for the destroy, I am intrigued and will go rewrite it. Thank you!